# How to save and load CSpect emulator state when emulating ZX Spectrum Next

Tags: emulation, zx-spectrum

I use [CSpect](http://cspect.org/) emulator for playing a game for [ZX Spectrum Next](https://www.specnext.com/). I wonder whether is possible to save the emulator state to memory and load it in the future in order to have game save/load functionality at an arbitrary place that is not supported by the game. There is such functionality with [Fuse](http://fuse-emulator.sourceforge.net/) emulator for older spectrum machines, but I cannot find how to do it with *CSpect*. If the functionality is not supported is there some other emulator for *ZX Spectrum Next* that supports it?

Comment: This does seem like a question of a modern day software emulating a modern day machine, doesn't it?

Comment: Modern day software that is actively updated. Shoot a question to the author, maybe? The chance is that if the function doesn't exists now, it can be implemented soon.

Comment: As the physical Spectrum Next doesn't have a Snapshot save facility, the emulator for the same thing doesn't have one as well.

Comment: @Raffzahn Really a modern-day machine with up to 2MB of RAM and up to 28Mhz Z80 instruction set CPU. The machine is retro in its characteristics despite the fact that it is modern-day produced. Also, it has backward compatibility with the classical ZX Spectrum which is a real retro machine. The emulator in question is also an emulator for classical ZX Spectrum machines and not only for ZX Spectrum Next. I think that the question is a good fit for the retrocomputing.stackexchange and that your attitude is extremely nagging and unfriendly.

Comment: This question is about how to handle a software that is currently under active development. How to, if at all possible, make a  memory dump in that software have no retro computing aspect.

Comment: @bobeff Not sure why you try to turn a friendly reminder into a personal argument. In any case it would be a good idea to [check the guidelines](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/), most notably [the ones about on/off-topic](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/634/6659) before trying to push your opinion. The Spectrum Next (with it's fantastic specs) is not a retro machine in sense of RC.SE. As Tofo (usually quite proficient in all things Spectrum) notes, the feature asked is neither present in the original Specy, nor in the Next.